# Smooth homotopy but not smooth isotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory

When reading Milnor’s *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint*, I thought of a problem, but I couldn’t solve it.

The question is:
Let f, g be diffeomorphisms from manifold X to Y(X, Y $\subset R^k$ ).Is there exists a **smooth homotopy** between f and g but **doesn’t** exist a **smooth isotopy** between f and g ?Please give an example.